# Laravel api header request

Tags: laravel, api

Route::resource('get-users','api\UserController@get_users');
Route::resource('register','api\UserController@register');

My Api is giving me the response I checked it using POSTMAN but android developer is asking me that what should he sent in header for my API . 
I am not getting that how to create a header I am using laravel and I have written functions in controller .

Comment: this is not about your problem but you should not use Route::resource for all routes. Just use http methods that you need. Eg:  Route::get('get-users','api\UserController@get_users');   Route::post('register','api\UserController@register');

Comment: are you planning on returning json from your api? perhaps the `accept` header for json

Comment: Yes I am returning json from the api

Answer (score 0):

You should go through this part of the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses

He maybe wants additional header in the response.
Your return value in `api\UserController` can be extended like this:

```
return response($content)
        ->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => $type,
            'X-Header-One' => 'Header Value',
            'X-Header-Two' => 'Header Value',
        ]);
```

Comment: what type of value should i place in it?

Comment: my type is json so should i use ('content-type' =>'json') ?

Comment: depends on what you achieve. What is the request from the android developer?

Comment: he just asked from me the api url which i have given , also asked that what should he needs to send in header and I DID NOT MAKE ANY HEADER IN MY API.